# Gettings hits per seconds per ip address from apache log

Tags: apache, rate-limiting

Im about to implement som rate limiting in varnish based on ip address. To get an idea of how much each ip adress hits the site i need to make a list of hits / second / ip.

The log format is nsca, does anybody have some hints to how to get that data ? my suggesting was to put ip and timestamp into mysql and maybe from there make a query, but i cant get my head around how to make the query, and maybe in can even be done from a shell script.

Any ideas are welcome.